# Logic Apps Create HTML Table with multiple lines

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a working HTTP trigger logic app that sends an email with info provided in the HTTP Post body, the workflow is very simple as shown below.

[image]

The HTTP Post body contains a property called Table which contains an HTML formatted table when it's sent the email contains additional characters highlighted in the email screenshot below

A sample of the body content

```
{ 
"To": "email@domain.com",
  "Subject": "emailSubject",
  "Body": "some info",
  "Table": [
    "<table>",
    "<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>",
    "<tr><th>Owner Name</th><th>Subscriptions</th><th>Application Names</th><th>Owned Resources Count</th><th>Total Resources Cost</th></tr>",
    "<tr><td>Owner1</td><td>Sub1<BR>Sub2<BR>moehe-devtest</td><td>App1<BR>App2<BR>App3</td><td>count1</td><td>amount1</td></tr>",
    "<tr><td>Owner2</td><td>Sub1<BR>Sub2<BR>Sub3<BR>Sub4<BR>Sub5</td><td>App1<BR>App2<BR>App3<BR>App4<BR>App5<BR>App6<BR>App7<BR>App8</td><td>Counr2</td><td>Amount2</td></tr>",
    "</table>"
  ]
}
```

The Email Sample with the unwanted characters:
[image]

I tried to send the Table property in JSON format and use the Create HTML Table Action instead to create the HTML Table but although the unwanted characters disappeared the items in the cells are not displayed in multiple lines so I need help to either remove the unwanted characters from the original flow or to display the items in multiple lines with the Create HTML Table action.

[image]

Comment: I found that using Create HTML table is producing a clean table, however my issue was to print each item in a different line so I managed to add a symbol @ between each item then I added a replace action to replace @ with <br> and voila, it worked perfectly.
for the borders, I already handled it on the html page header as you see in the screenshot.

Comment: how did you solve for this? my replace statements are getting escaped by logic apps: ```<td>[&quot;External/Factset/Benchmarks/2021&lt;br&gt;External/Factset/Benchmarks/2021/08&lt```

Comment: @Dumbledore__ Did you ever figure it out? I am getting the exact same annoying problem

Comment: @Bassie apologies I left this company and can't exactly recall how I solved for this.