# Why does my logic app not respect new lines when creating an html table?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-logic-apps, kql

I have set up an alert in Azure which checks whether there are any exceptions 15 minutes, by running the below query and then pinging my logic app

In the logic app I create an html table with the query results like this

[image]

However, the value output for `htmlStackTrace` (`items()?['htmlStackTrace']`) does not render my newlines (`\r` or `\n`) and shows the whole stack trace stack in one blob

I tried adding `<br>`s instead of newlines, but they got encoded and display as `&lt;br&gt;`

I even tried replacing them with `~`s and then in my logic app swaping them out with pre-encoded tags, but then the encoded string just gets rendered in the cell

How can I get the logic app html to respect these newlines?

My KQL query:

```
exceptions
| where timestamp > now() - 20m
| order by timestamp desc
| project 
    timestamp,
    innermostMessage,
    outerMessage,
    type=['type'],
    customDimensions,
    details=['details'],
    operation_Id
| mv-expand details
| mv-expand parsedStack=details.parsedStack 
| extend ourParsedStack=parsedStack 
| summarize 
    Timestamp=any(timestamp),
    StackTrace=make_set(
        strcat(
            parsedStack.level, ' ', 
            parsedStack.assembly, ' ', 
            parsedStack.fileName, 
            iff(isnull(parsedStack.fileName), 
                '', 
                strcat(': ', parsedStack.line)))),
    HtmlStackTrace=strcat_array(
        make_set(
            strcat(
                ourParsedStack.level, ' ', 
                ourParsedStack.assembly, ' ', 
                ourParsedStack.method, ' ', 
                ourParsedStack.fileName, 
                iff(isnull(ourParsedStack.fileName), 
                    '', 
                    strcat(': ', ourParsedStack.line)))), "\r\n\r\n")
    by 
    operation_Id,
    OuterMessage=outerMessage,
    InnerMessage=innermostMessage,
    RequestPath=tostring(customDimensions.RequestPath),
    Exception=type
```

Code from the Create HTML Table in the logic app

```
"Create_HTML_table_2": {
    "inputs": {
        "columns": [
            {
                "header": "timestamp",
                "value": "@item()?['timestamp']"
            },
            {
                "header": "exception",
                "value": "@item()?['exception']"
            },
            {
                "header": "outerMessage",
                "value": "@item()?['outerMessage']"
            },
            {
                "header": "InnerMessage",
                "value": "@item()?['innerMessage']"
            },
            {
                "header": "htmlStackTrace",
                "value": "@replace(item()?['htmlStackTrace'], '~', '&lt;br&gt;')"
            }
        ],
        "format": "HTML",
        "from": "@body('Run_query_and_list_results')?['value']"
    },
    "runAfter": {},
    "type": "Table"
},
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66068537/logic-apps-create-html-table-with-multiple-lines and https://ostack.cn/qa/?qa=175759/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write HTML inside HTML Table Azure Logic Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852920/write-html-inside-html-table-azure-logic-apps)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT I have tried all the suggested solutions but I only ever get either encoded tags, or empty srtings. I am currently trying another logic-app action, 'visualise log results'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired output by using 'Run query and visualise results' instead of running the query and then building the html table manually (or using Create HTML Table):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default when you add '\n' the logic app adds an extra '' and so try removing extra '' from **code view** of your logic app.

In your case try using `@concat(item()?['htmlStackTrace'], '\r\n\r\n')`.

Below is a sample you can refer to

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]